# Gridelements is empty

Tags: typo3, tx-gridelements

I'm using the Typo3 v10.4 and Gridelements v10, i did include the Typoscript templates W/Dataprocessing but i get an empty div container(i get the fluid html code but not the {data.tx_gridelements_view_column_200-> f:format.raw()})

, i did not include the depricated Typoscript templates for gridelements.
if i include them i get the content from the backend but i loose the fluid/html configuration.

2col.html fluid file

```
<html xmlns:f="http://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/CMS/Fluid/ViewHelpers" data-namespace-typo3-fluid="true">

<f:layout name="Default"/>

<f:section name="Main">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            {data.tx_gridelements_view_column_200-> f:format.raw()}
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            {data.tx_gridelements_view_column_300-> f:format.raw()}
        </div>
    </div>
</f:section>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the dataProcessing approach there is no such thing as `data.tx_gridelements_view_column_200` anymore.

Just put `<f:debug>{_all}</f:debug>` in your template to get an overview of the available array structure.

If you are on the default setup, everything relevant should be within the `children` key of that array.

You can also take a look into the default templates and partials provided by Gridelements within the `Resources/Private` folder to get a grasp on how it's done now.

Comment: Yes, good advice, Resources/Private folder is the right place to look, thanks!

Comment: Is there a solution? I've got the same problem. <f:debug>{_all}</f:debug> doesnt work because there is no output (debug is on)